# numpy.hstack with strings and numbers removes decimals

Tags: python, string, numpy, append, decimal

I am trying to create a table to export in CSV. I have to attach different numerical values (with decimals), and I would like also to attach an indicator column. This is formed by empty spaces '_' and 'X', in order to help me with the post-process of the data.
As you can see in the code below, while I append only numerical values the decimals are present, whereas if I append the string column the decimals values disappears.

I think I will use numerical values also for the indicator column, but I would like to understand this behaviour. Is it possible to attach string columns and numerical values avoiding the elimination of the decimals?

```
>>> c = np.hstack((b,error_perc_notabs_array,error_array))
>>> c
array([[  3.63200000e-01,   6.52800000e-01,   4.70400000e-01,
          2.13117665e-02,   2.52124411e-02,   1.83029153e+01,
          3.90067457e-03],
       [  4.16000000e-01,   7.82400000e-01,   4.48000000e-01,
          2.25692703e-02,   4.35769819e-02,   9.30810405e+01,
          2.10077116e-02]])
>>> z
[array([' '], 
      dtype='|S1'), array(['X'], 
      dtype='|S1')]
>>> shape(z)
(2L, 1L)
>>> d = np.hstack((z,c))
>>> d
array([[' ', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
       ['X', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '9', '0']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy convert all elements to a common datatype, which is, in your case `S1`, strings of length 1.

Despite this, my test shows, that the common datatype os `S1` and `float` is `S32`:

```
>>> z = array([['X'],[' ']], dtype='S1')
>>> d = numpy.hstack((z,c))
>>> d
array([[b'X', b'0.3632', b'0.6528', b'0.4704', b'0.0213117665',
        b'0.0252124411', b'18.3029153', b'0.00390067457'],
       [b' ', b'0.416', b'0.7824', b'0.448', b'0.0225692703',
        b'0.0435769819', b'93.0810405', b'0.0210077116']], 
      dtype='|S32')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel for the answer! Which version of Python are you using? I am using Python 2.7.6.4 on WinPython. Do you think it depends on this?